# Delete part of a div

Tags: jquery

I've got a div:

```
<div class="team"><img src="images/logo/team.png" style="vertical-align:middle"> Team</div>
```

Is there any way in jQuery to delete only the image in this div? To make it look like this:

```
<div class="team"> Team</div>
```

And another question. Is there any way to delete the old image and add a new one after the text? Something like this:

```
<div class="team"> Team<img src="images/logo/new.png" style="vertical-align:middle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

as in `$( "div > img" ).remove();`

Edit:  `$(function() { $( "div.team > div" ).remove(); });`  is more specific, and just a reminder here to do it when the document has loaded.

Comment: Probably add a class to the `div` selector, but still just as effective with what we're shown.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the element, use [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$('div.team > img').remove();
```

To append another element, use [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('div.team').append('ELEMENT');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cu15zr8k/3/

---

If you just want change the `src` attribute, is better you use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('div.team > img').attr('src', 'new-url');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cu15zr8k/2/

Answer (score 0):

`$('#team > img').remove()`
However if you want to just change the image you could target the image and change the src attribute like this: `$('#team > img').attr('src', url);`
Where url is the path to the image you want to reference

Answer (score -1):

Easy enough to get rid of the image using numerous approaches

```
$('div.team img').remove()
```

or just replace html with the text

```
$('div.team').html(function(){
   return $(this).text()
});
```

to add a different one use `append()

```
$('div.team').append( $('<img>',{src:'/path/to/image'}) );
```